# ImageView with bounds larger than screen is hidden

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have an `imageview` within a `scrollview`. However, upon rotation, the image height in landscape is larger than the screen. This causes the `imageview` to disappear. This is not a memory issue as I have removed the setting of the image itself and just set a background color. If I set a smaller height, the imageview does not disappear. Is there any way to prevent the imageview from disappearing when it has a height bigger than the screen?

Comment: can you post your layout xml file?

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to use `Display` class  this is full example for it

```
    //get Display info
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    //get screen h/w
    int w = d.getWidth();  
    int h = d.getHeight(); 

    ImageView img = ( ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.myimage);

    //i want to set imageview full screen for example
    img.getLayoutParams().height = h; 
    img.getLayoutParams().width  = w;

    // and this to set h or w by percentage let say 15% of screen 
    img.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(h/100)*15; 
    img.getLayoutParams().width  = (int)(w/100)*15; 

//or if height large than screen resize it
if ( img.getHeight() > h)
{
  img.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(h/100)*95;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: this resizes the imageview - I do not want to resize it.

Comment: `Is there any way to prevent the imageview from disappearing when it has a height bigger than the screen?` you have to resize it i don't think there is other way